# Using both git2 and hyper: openssl linked more than once

Tags: openssl, rust, rust-cargo, hyper

I'm trying to build something which is using both hyper and git2 at the same time. Now I've got a problem with openssl being linked twice. A tip by [shepmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster) lead me to Cargos `features` and I tried that but I'm still stuck.

The precise error I'm getting upon `cargo build` is the following:

```
error: native library `openssl` is being linked to by more than one version of the same package, but it can only be linked once; try updating or pinning your dependencies to ensure that this package only shows up once

  openssl-sys v0.7.17
  openssl-sys v0.9.1
```

As far as I can tell openssl is required both by git2 and hyper. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Since I disabled the default features for hyper (and cookie for good measure) openssl should not be required by it anymore. I've looked through the lock file to see if `openssl` is required by anything else but I couldn't find anything. But I still get the error. Unfortunately cargo doesn't tell me where the dependency comes from.

Here's my `Cargo.toml`'s dependency section and the lock file:

```
[dependencies]
openssl = "0.9.1"
hoedown = "5.0.0"
iron = "0.4.0"
webbrowser = "0.1.3"
router = "0.4.0"
staticfile = "0.3.1"
clap = "2.18.0"
lazy_static = "0.2.2"
linked-hash-map = "0.3.0"
params = "0.5.0"
git2 = "0.6.1"

[dependencies.yaml-rust]
version = "0.3.4"
features = ["preserve_order"]

[dependencies.hyper]
version = "0.9.12"
default-features = false

[dependencies.cookie]
version = "0.2.5"
default-features = false
```

Here's the [Cargo.lock](https://gist.github.com/machisuji/fea6186ea550277808b26aa75d652d2c) in case that's of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the combination of params and openssl:

```
[dependencies]
openssl = "0.9.1"
params = "0.5.0"
```

[params 0.5](https://crates.io/crates/params/0.5.0) requires multipart 0.8, with features `server`, but [without](https://github.com/iron/params/blob/master/Cargo.toml) `default-features = false`:

```
[dependencies.multipart]
features = ["server"]
version = "0.8"
```

That means [multipart 0.8](https://crates.io/crates/multipart/0.8.1) will also require [hyper 0.9](https://crates.io/crates/hyper/0.9.12). And hyper (using the default features) requires openssl 0.7.

There is a [ticket](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/907) in hyper to switch to a newer openssl version.

Comment: Thanks! I just want to parse a posted JSON body. Ok I'll just have to drop params then and find something else to do that.

Comment: @Machisuji I created a [pull request](https://github.com/iron/params/pull/31) for params which should fix that.

Comment: @Machisuji it has been fixed, your original example is now working, as params 0.5.0 will be [used automatically](http://doc.crates.io/specifying-dependencies.html) now.